# Someone signed up to a website using my Email address and was created from my IP, but with a different browser?

Tags: ip-spoofing, email-spoofing

Can anyone tell me if this is a hack? otherwise how did they use my email, a different browser and my IP address to create the account?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: we need more details if you want us to determine if it is a 'hack' - how do you know that a different browser was used?

Comment: Aren't there any other devices on your home or office network (if that's what you mean by "my IP address")? What other info can you give, so that we don't speculate too far into the wild?

Comment: I would change your WIFI password, and if your router allows you to - check the device list of connected devices and verify you know what they all are. Someone can connect to your WIFI and catch your traffic. Since behind a router all devices will appear to have the same external IP Address, it does not mean it is your computer per se, but maybe just another one on your wifi network

Comment: Maybe you did it from a tablet or mobile device? On the WLAN it will have the same IP and it will be a different user agent string.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you got an email stating that you registered to a website. Firstly, I wouldn't be surprised if this was some form of elaborate phishing. Double check the website before visiting or avoid it all together.

Secondly, as a person above stated, It could be, that there is some form of malware on your PC that hijacks your information (Script or a plugin), although very unlikely.

Lastly, you sure you haven't noticed any suspicious activity or processes running on your computer? It seems like a very odd scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how you know that it used your IP and "a different browser" but Im guessing you got a registration confirmation with this information included?

If it was actually your IP it sounds like you may have been attacked in some way. There is several possibilities how this could have been done.

- One might be some remote desktop solution with a weak password?
- Another way could have been malicious websites/javascripts and so on
  that in some way took control over your browser.
- It could be a very well executed [Spear Phishing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing#Spear_phishing)
- One very common solution to this is that you simply forgot that you
  registered.

Comment: I am thinking that he received a **registration email with his IP**, email and a random browser name on it. The IP and email could easily have been obtained when he visited another "affiliated" website and, at the first impression, not related. It seems a technique to make the person feel the need to visit the website in order to check/cancel the registration. This may not require malware to be present in his machine and I believe it's unlikely he "forgot" registering in there, since the reported browser is not even the same (perhaps not even installed in his PC).

Comment: @Armfoot The correct browser could easily have been obtained in the same way though. I'm note sure why they would add a random browser in this case

Comment: @Kapep 3 possibilities came to my mind: perhaps the browser may have not been part of the data obtained, so they filled it out randomly; perhaps they intentionally changed the browser's name in order to "motivate" the person to visit the website; or maybe the OP is using a chromium based browser and the name *chrome* was used...

Answer (score 1):

Your IP and email can be obtained when you visit other websites.

If you received a registration email from an unknown website with this data, besides the possibility of malware existing in your PC, another likely scenario is that they have obtained that information when you registered or updated information in a website known to you. The people from this unknown website may have obtained this information either legally or, most likely, illegally (i.e. stealing)... They also may have not had the browser name information upon sending that email, therefore a default/popular's browser name may have been used in the email.

This technique can **obtain more information about your machine/yourself when you access that unknown website**. Therefore it is preferable to not visit any link referenced in that registration email. If you want to know more about that unknown website, do not access it directly, i.e. find information about it through search engines with, for example, the words "phishing" or "scam".